# un-minimize (restore) a pyglet window programmatically

Tags: python, operating-system, window, pyglet

Is there a way to programmatically reverse the action of `window.minimize()` in pyglet? I came across an [answer](https://pyglet-users.narkive.com/m5xk1OFI/un-minimize-a-window-programmatically) in a forum from 15 years ago that suggests adding the following code to `/pyglet/window/win32/init.py`:

```
def restore(self):
    _user32.ShowWindow(self._hwnd, SW_RESTORE)
```

I have not tested this solution yet as it would require me to modify the package source for each installation. I'm wondering if there is a more up-to-date method for restoring a window in pyglet. The forum post I referenced seems to be the only source discussing this issue, also the [official documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html#pyglet.window.Window) does not mention a similar method at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using `win32gui`. Here's the code snippet that worked for me:

```
import win32gui, win32con

def restore(window: pyglet.window.Window):
    win32gui.ShowWindow(window._hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
```

To restore the window specified by `window._hwnd`, I used the `ShowWindow` function. The `win32con.SW_RESTORE` constant (which equals to 9) just indicates the action of restoring.